# mutt: configure index color based on To: header

Tags: configuration, mutt

i access proton mail through mutt and i've added a custom domain that goes through the proton account. therefore my INBOX has incoming mail to 2 different addresses. i'd like to color (in the index screen) only those emails that are addressed to the custom account:

like this in muttrc:

`color index none green default me@custom_domain.com`

but it doesn't work. i have no problems coloring the line by setting the pattern to a specific `From:` address. like:

`color index none green default myfriend@some_email.com` works perfectly.

i can also set the pattern from the subject or body... but NOT the `To:` header. why is this and how do i change it?

(just to be clear: i am not trying to change the colors in the pager header section, but rather in the index itself)

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. hope this helps someone later:

`color index none green default '~C me@custom_domain.com'`

didn't need the `~C` for selecting from other fields. only for To:

this helps me see at a glance which of my accounts they were sending to.

Comment: Note that `~C` checks both the `To:` and `Cc:` headers which is likely what you want. If you wanted to check the `To:` one only, that'd be `~t`.

Comment: See doc at http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#patterns and http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#color

Comment: See also the `~p` pattern.